# How can I get a reference to the current UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In Objective-C, what is the best way of getting a reference to the current UINavigationController?  I would like to gain access to it from any class that may not have a reference to a UIController, delegate, or anything else.

Is there an existing way to get the current UINavigationController?  Should I add something to my application delegate, and retrieve that?

Comment: You can create a property in appDelegate, create base view controller subclass, override viewWillAppear and set there `appDelegate.currentNavigationController = self.navigationController;`

Comment: But accessing from 'any class' can brake MVC, why your custom view should know about navigation?..

Comment: In this particular case, I may need to push on a login UIController.  I have web services running asynchronously working all types of things.  If one receives an Authentication problem, it needs to pop up a box to have the user login.

Comment: If your navigation controller is the window's root view controller, you can access it with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];`

Comment: It would be better to use an NSNotification for this purpose, rather than break the MVC paradigm.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As it turns out, you can get it, albeit with quite a bit of dot syntax, from any UIView/UIViewController descendant.

```
self.(view).window.rootViewController.navigationController;
```

If you are using an object that descends from any other class, the same is true, except you must go through `UIApplication`

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.navigationController;
```

Of course, both of these break MVC in a big way, and it is definitely recommended that any logic that must touch the "default navigation controller" be added to the root view controller.

Comment: I tried this in my tvOS app and found that `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController` gave me a perfectly usable UINavigationController. `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.navigationController` on the other hand returned nil! So if your root view is a UINavigationController, you may have to adjust this slightly.

Comment: that returns nil

Comment: This works  [Wain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36514217/1725535)

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4:**

```
guard let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }
```